# How to get fields from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I want to get fields from 2 different tables . The last field `candidate_score_id` has a many to one relationship. So how should I join the below 2 queries

1) To get `candidate_score_id` from the `candidate_score` table.

```
select candidate_score_id from candidate_score a where 
a.assessment_id = NEW.assessment_id and
a.candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id and
a.attempt_Count = NEW.attempt_count;
```

2) To insert different fields in to the `candidate_score_details` table. The field in this table should be obtained by query above.

```
insert into candidate_score_details(candidate_score_details_id, candidate_id, assessment_id, attempt_count, score_type, score_tag,correct, candidate_score_id)
select uuid();
select a.candidate_id, a.assessment_id,a.attempt_count,"BY-COMPLEXITY",
case c.complexity 
when 1 then "HIGH"
when 2 then "MEDIUM"
when 3 then "LOW" 
end, count(*) from candidate_answer a, answer_key b, question_meta_data c where a.candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id and 
a.assessment_id = NEW.assessment_id and
a.attempt_count = NEW.attempt_count and
a.assessment_id = b.assessment_id and 
a.question_id = b.question_number and 
a.response = b.answer and 
a.question_id = c.question_number 
group by a.candidate_id, a.assessment_id, a.attempt_count, c.complexity;
```

Comment: You want to run these queries from java using JDBC?

Comment: Oops!!! I generally post on java forum. Sorry. I'll change the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the SQL joining aspect of your question, you'll need to specify the table I THINK you're aliasing a 2nd table with the "NEW" reference.  If that's the case, then the query would be (replacing "OTHER_TABLE_NAME" with the name of the 2nd table:

```
select a.candidate_score_id 
from candidate_score a 
  left join OTHER_TABLE_NAME new on 
   and a.assessment_id = NEW.assessment_id
   and a.candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id 
   and a.attempt_Count = NEW.attempt_count
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Query 1 has the same 3 criteria on the "candidate_score" table as for the "candidate_answer" table in Query 2.
So how about adding a LEFT JOIN of "candidate_score" to "candidate_answer" on those 3 fields?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO candidate_score_details 
(
  candidate_score_details_id, 
  candidate_id, 
  assessment_id, 
  attempt_count, 
  score_type, 
  score_tag,
  correct, 
  candidate_score_id
)
SELECT 
 uuid(), 
 answer.candidate_id, 
 answer.assessment_id,
 answer.attempt_count,
 'BY-COMPLEXITY' AS score_type,
 (CASE meta.complexity 
  WHEN 1 THEN 'HIGH'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'MEDIUM'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'LOW' 
  END) AS score_tag, 
 COUNT(*) AS correct,
 MAX(score.candidate_score_id) AS max_candidate_score_id
FROM candidate_answer AS answer
JOIN answer_key AS akey 
  ON (akey.assessment_id = answer.assessment_id AND akey.question_number = answer.question_id AND akey.answer = answer.response)
LEFT JOIN candidate_score AS score 
  ON (score.candidate_id = answer.candidate_id AND score.assessment_id = answer.assessment_id AND score.attempt_count = answer.attempt_count)
LEFT JOIN question_meta_data AS meta 
  ON meta.question_number = answer.question_id
WHERE answer.candidate_id = NEW.candidate_id 
  AND answer.assessment_id = NEW.assessment_id
  AND answer.attempt_count = NEW.attempt_count
GROUP BY answer.candidate_id, answer.assessment_id, answer.attempt_count, meta.complexity;
```